# DirectX Multiple devices and objects for each control

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

So I have multiple controls I want to render scenes to.
I have a Device instance for each control as well as several other objects like shaders I need to compile for each control and so on.

I wonder if this is a good approach to have multiple devices and all the objects for each control?

I get pretty good performance from it though. It's just I want to save memory and setup time. Because for example the shaders are the same for each instance and need to be loaded and compiled each time. I can't have them statically because they are restricted to the same device when I tried. I tried to make the Device static and so I can have the shader objects static too, but I seem to run in a problem where the context gets corrupted, even if only one thread executes them. Maybe it is because I can't rely that the GUI thread will always finish the context (which is statically used by all controls) state and render before going to the next and this corrupts my state.

So my issue and concern is more about the memory it needs and time to load (feels pretty slow and heavy), than the performance of drawing (which is pretty good and satisying). I read there are no "best practices" in general but maybe some of you have some hints what I could improve.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a different device for each control, I think it is better to create a different swap chain for each control and all controls/swapchains to share/be created by the same device.

Comment: Maybe, I would still need different contexts in that case though.

Comment: No the context will also be the same.

Comment: Yes but I mean I think I would still get the context "corruption" if I don't use different ones. You are right it would be the same, but I think I would face the similar issue I explained in the question.

Comment: The memory consumption would be much less with a single device/context for sure.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstand the context concept. Because I tried it with a single device and single context and it behaved very weirdly. Maybe single device and context for each control.